# Date coding issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, date, datetime

In my company front end system shows the "proper" date but when i am querying the database from embarcaderoRapid SQL it shows me date as a below (database) .

Its a problem for me as in our front end view we are not able to group results etc and i can do it in embarcadero.

But i need to understand what is the logic behind this date "transformation" ?

Any thoughts ?

Ofcourse i could mapp it as i figured out whats everymonth code but without understanding i will have to to this for every new month.

```
front end           database
01/04/2015 00:000   1427842800000
01/04/2015 00:000   1427842800000
01/05/2015 00:000   1430434800000
01/05/2015 00:000   1430434800000
01/05/2015 00:000   1430434800000
01/06/2015 00:000   1433113200000
01/06/2015 00:000   1433113200000
01/07/2015 00:000   1435705200000
01/07/2015 00:000   1435705200000
01/08/2015 00:000   1438383600000
01/08/2015 00:000   1438383600000
```

**EDIT:**

Thank You for You response.
You are near the answer.

Is there any function or a method in SQL/EXCEL to convert this timestamp to date we usually see ?

I also checked `04/01/2015 @ 12:00am (UTC) == 1427846400.` and got same results.
No sure why this is happening as my database shows 1427842800000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TS bigint
Set @TS ='1427842800000'
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,60,DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @TS % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, @TS / 1000, '19700101')))
```

**Edit**: to Account for Timezone

Comment: and this one gives me 2015-03-31 23:00:00.000 which is not correct (mine is 01.04.2015) . also i am its oracle database-i should state that in my first post

Comment: The values are stored in UTC in the database. Your front end is converting those to values specific to your timezone.

Comment: check now @rafalbballer

Comment: its great thank You . Anyway its not working in oracle database. any thoughts about that ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

In the database you have a date stored as a timestamp, i.e. the number of seconds since 1/1/1970. In your frontend, the date is displayed as we usually see a date.

See: http://www.unixtimestamp.com/, when i'm writing this answer the date is `1444122272`.

**EDIT** : by the way, your frontend date must be in a specific timezone because `04/01/2015 @ 12:00am (UTC) == 1427846400`.

Answer (score 0):

Try **from-unixtime()** function.Official link is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).